# Underscores Wordpress Theme - Adding second sidebar

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, sidebar

Stared a Wordpress site using Underscores theme (_s)

I have got one sidebar working but want to make a second one to be on the same page. (containing different widgets)

I have added the new sidebar to the functions.php and it appears in the Wordpress login screen and i can drop widgets into it. However, I can't get it to show on the actual webpage. (the first sidebar is working fine)

Anyone know how to do this or know a tutorial...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the "sidebar.php" file in your theme folder. It should normally be:

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>

    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <?php endif; // end sidebar-1 widget area ?>

</div><!-- #secondary -->
```

You will need to add another if statement that looks out for the other sidebar. Be sure to  reference it by whatever you used in the functions.php file.

If you want it to appear below the current sidebar, just be sure to add it before closing the 'div' so it will still be in the same column. I used 'sidebar-lower':

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>

    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
    <?php endif; // end sidebar-1 widget area ?>

    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-lower' ) ) : ?>
    <?php endif; // end sidebar-lower widget area ?>

</div><!-- #secondary -->
```